# jQuery code not hiding columns when I click on it on the select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide and show the columns as to what is selected and what is not selected but something is not working. I am unable to filter it out.

Here is my code which was working but not any more, I'm not sure what went wrong.

```html
<select name="column_name" id="column_name" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple>
  <option data-column="0" class="link toggle-vis" value="0">ID</option>
  <option data-column="1" class="link toggle-vis" value="1">Name</option>
  <option data-column="2" class="link toggle-vis" value="2">Code</option>
  <option data-column="3" class="link toggle-vis" value="3">Number</option>
  <option data-column="4" class="link toggle-vis" value="4">Age</option>
  <option data-column="5" class="link toggle-vis" value="5">Sex</option>
  <option data-column="6" class="link toggle-vis" value="6">Occupation</option>
  <option data-column="7" class="link toggle-vis" value="7">Status</option>
  <option data-column="8" class="link toggle-vis" value="8">Country</option>
  <option data-column="9" class="link toggle-vis" value="9">Parish</option>
  <option data-column="10" class="link toggle-vis" value="10">Village</option>
  <option data-column="11" class="link toggle-vis" value="11">District</option>
  <option data-column="12" class="link toggle-vis" value="12">Email</option>
  <option data-column="13" class="link toggle-vis" value="13">Phone</option>
  <option data-column="14" class="link toggle-vis" value="14">Photo</option>
  <option data-column="15" class="link toggle-vis" value="15">Marital</option>
  <option data-column="16" class="link toggle-vis" value="16">Registeredby</option>
  <option data-column="17" class="link toggle-vis" value="17">Lastname</option>
  <option data-column="18" class="link toggle-vis" value="18">Birthdate</option>
  <option data-column="19" class="link toggle-vis" value="19">CreationDate</option>
</select>
```

```js
$('#column_name').selectpicker();

$('#column_name').click(function() {
  var all_column = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];
  var remove_column = $('#column_name').attr('data-column');
  var remaining_column = all_column.filter(function(obj) {
    return remove_column.indexOf(obj) == -1;
  });
  
  dt.columns(remove_column).visible(false);
  dt.columns(remaining_column).visible(true);
});
```

Here is the image. When I check it I want it hidden and should not be displayed:

https://prnt.sc/upY5bdNfiN87

I am using the selectpicker bootstrap plugin for this

Comment: Id `dt` a reference to a data table? Also, you should use the `change` event when dealing with select elements, not `click`

Comment: select elements typically use change, not click.

Comment: now i am getting an error , `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
    at index.html?action=manage:412:42
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (index.html?action=manage:411:51)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5183:27)
    at elemData.handle (jquery.js:4991:28)
    at z.fn.triggerNative (bootstrap-select.js:386:10)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-select.js:2479:18)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5183:27)
    at elemData.handle (jquery.js:4991:28)`

Comment: yes dt is referred to datatable